# How much glue down LVP can be installed in a day?

Tags: flooring

How much glue-down LVP can realistically be installed per hour or in a full day? I'm thinking somewhere around 100 sq ft an hour (minus spreading glue and waiting for it to set up ) putting me at 600 sq ft roughly in a 9-hour day assuming it takes 30 minutes to spread about 300 sq ft of glue at a time and wait 1 hour (manufacture specs) for it to set up before laying flooring. Not sure if that's realistic though since i've only ever installed floating LVP and tile where waiting for glue to set up isn't a factor. Layout is fairly standard, bedroom, office, kitchen, dining room, bathroom, closets, etc.

Comment: Depends on experience.  First time might be too fast, tenth time might be slow.  If doing different sections, can lay down floor while waiting for next section of glue to set, but experience counts on laying down glue and having enough time to lay down flooring.

Comment: Is there a concern here with leaving a portion of the floor undone until the next day?